# Show Application getting stuck

Tags: 18.04

When I click the "Show Application" in Ubuntu 18.04, it opens but it is impossible to close it :/ It doesn't close no matter how much time I click on it, it just do the fade in animation. I have no choice to restart my pc each time I need to go on show application

Answer (score 0):

Simply type the <kbd>**Esc**</kbd> or the <kbd>**Super**</kbd> (Windows key) , this should close the app-page.

Comment: The problem is that it is not closing :/

Comment: can you take a screenshoot and post it?

Comment: Put also some more information, did you open "Show Application" on the dash, hot spot, ...?